# create table and clone one record from old table to new one

Tags: symfony

The situation is the following:
I have a table (PERSONS) with collection of records. it's structure:

```
id, 
created, 
modified, 
number, 
first_name, 
… (up to 30 positions)
```

This is the ‘bank’ of employees. Well, and I have to prepare, yearly archive of this table (such a black box for not used data). It should be done in four steps:

1. check if archive exists e.g. 2015_PERSONS
2. If no, create table 2015_PERSONS
3. copy single records from PERSONS table to 2015_PERSONS table
4. delete this record from PERSONS table

It isn’t difficult normal way but I try to do it without special entity for archive file, and I found some problems. First and fourth steps are easy for me but second and third not.
Second step is the following (in the PERSONS controller):

```
$manager  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$metadata = $manager->getClassMetadata(PERSONS::class);
$metadata->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => ‘2015_PERSONS’));
$schema = new SchemaTool($manager);
$schema->createSchema(array($metadata));
```

and the archive table is created but with one difference. In the first table “id” field is “bigint 12” autoincrement (MySQL) but in the second “id” is “int 11” autoincrenent and I don’t know why. The rest of fields (int, text, varchar) are the same. Definition in the PERSONS entity is the following:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;
```

But the root problem is with third step, because I can’t find the way to place data. I try to do it the following ways:

```
$data = $this->getRepo('PERSONS')->findOneBy(1);
$second = clone $data;
$second->setId(null);
$second->save();
```

OR

```
$second = new Second();
$second->fromArray($data->toArray());
$second->save();
```

And don’t know how to find handle for 2015_PERSONS table to save prepared data copy. Be so kind as to prompt me.

Comment: hm, why dont use `getManager()->persist()` and `->flush()` ? About copy to second object better use second way.

Comment: Hi, but I haven't entity for $second, so I can't flush() it. Right?

Comment: ok, so what is the `new Second()` and what method `save()` do?

Comment: It's my mistake, "Second" is like "something". Let's say. I know I have to create entity object (PERSONS entity) but I don't know hove to change table name in this new object to write data to the proper table. So I can call: **$second  = new PERSONS();** but don't know how to change table name yo 2015_PERSONS. That's my problem. I try to have one entity but use it to handle two tables.

Comment: Ok, I thing in that case you should use DQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know how to do it "manual" as I inform above, but I try to find more "Doctrine" way. Maybe by "Metadata" but I'm to fresh with Symfony2 to solve this problem by myself.